# Why i get wrong/incoherent results with this neural net?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am working to create a neural network to predict the future value of the forex currency pair EURUSD knowing values in the past 16 hours.

At first i had the value for every minute from 2000 to 2017.
To create the labeled data for training i have subdivided the minutes in groups of 960 and calculated the labels for every period in the following way:

To calcolate the label for the i *th* period i took the data from the i+1 *th* period and checked if during the i+1 *th* period the price goes above or below a certain percentage in respect to the price of the last minute of the i *th* period.

In short i have got about 6300 pairs of labeled data with 960 input values and 3 output classes each. (first class the price goes up more than X, second class the price goes down more than X, third class the price stays in the middle)

About 33% of the training data falls in the first class, another 33% falls in the second class and the last 33% falls in the third class.

You can find the data here: https://ufile.io/m15fa

My problem lies in the output. I am not able to obtain any usefull prediction.
Every execution of the script, after the training, the network classifies all of the test data in the same class, which changes nearly every execution of the script.

Here the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import json

print("Loading data...")
f = open('out_x.txt', 'r')
input_data_x = json.load(f)
print("1/2 loaded...")
f = open('out_y.txt', 'r')
input_data_y = json.load(f)
print("Done loading data.")

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.005
training_epochs = 10
batch_size = 10
num_examples = 5500
display_step = 1

print("------------------------------------")
print("learning_rate:",learning_rate)
print("training_epochs:",training_epochs)
print("batch_size:",batch_size)
print("num_examples:",num_examples)
print("data_x:",len(input_data_x))
print("data_y:",len(input_data_y))
print("------------------------------------")

# Network Parameters
n_input = 960
n_hidden_1 = 500 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_classes = 3 

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    # Hidden fully connected layer 
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each class
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Construct model
logits = multilayer_perceptron(X)

# Define loss asnd optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):

            batch_x = input_data_x[i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size]
            batch_y = input_data_y[i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                            Y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost={:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            # Test model
            pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Apply softmax to logits
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
            # Calculate accuracy
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
            print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: input_data_x[total_batch*batch_size :], Y: input_data_y[total_batch*batch_size :]}))


    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Apply softmax to logits
    prediction = tf.argmax(pred, 1)
    # Calculate accuracy
    output= sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={X: input_data_x})


    # Not-so-beautiful-code to try to debug the problem
    # You can remove it

    i0 = 0
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0

    for x in output:
        if x == 0: i0 +=1
        elif x == 1: i1 +=1
        elif x == 2: i2 +=1
        #else: print(x)
        print(x, end='')



    print(i0, i1, i2)
```

Please help me sort this out

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to add an activation function (relu, sigmoid) but without success. I have also tried to add another hidden layer but things don't change.

Comment: You are missing a non-linear activation function in your MLP.